# Glide me disminuye el tamaño de la ImageView

Tags: android, android-glide

Tengo el siguiente código para mostrar una serie de imágenes desde una Url:

```
 String internetUrl = "internet url";
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imvImagen);
        Glide
                .with(Principal.this)
                .load(internetUrl)
                .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                .into(img);
    }


};
```

Todo va bien pero cuando voy avanzando por las imágenes se va reduciendo el tamaño de la misma, hasta llegar a ser diminutas. ( las 10 primeras imagenes se ven a tamaño normal) ¿a que se puede deber?
Aqui va mi XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnBajar"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@drawable/btnbajar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnShare"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/btnshare"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnSubir"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/btnsubir"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imvImagen"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnBajar"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
   />
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final la solucion era mas sencilla de lo que pensaba, modifique el ImageView como sigue y solucionado

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imvImagen"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnBajar"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    />
```

Comment: antes del valor fill_parent (obsoleto) usa el match_parent

Answer (score 1):

Especifica una medida especifica mediante el método [`override()`](https://futurestud.io/blog/glide-image-resizing-scaling), por ejemplo:

```
...
...
    .override(500,500)
    .into(img);
```

También puedes hacer uso del método `fitCenter()` :

```
...
...
 .fitCenter()
 .override(500,500)
 .into(img);
```

otra opción es usando `match_parent` para siempre tener un alto y ancho definido por el contenedor.

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```